# webkit-box-shadow:inset not working on Chrome Version 48.0.2564.109

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a problem with webkit-boxshadow it doesn't work in latest chrome browser
this is the code can any give solution please. it works good in firefox.

```
option:checked { box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #2eb135 inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 5pc -5px 100px #2eb135 inset;}

option:hover{-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 2px #CCCCCC inset;}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) the box-shadow property does not need a prefix anymore. So you would be fine with just using the following styles:

```
option:checked {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 100px #2eb135;
}

option:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 8px 2px #CCCCCC;
}
```

Comment: i checked this code still not working in chrome see this link http://prntscr.com/a4rf5q

Answer (score 0):

It does work. You might want to reconsider your parameters. Don't you think 100px spread is a bit much? Try decreasing that value!

Sample:

```css
.c-test {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f00;
}

.c-test__ok {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #2eb135 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5pc -5px 10px #2eb135 inset;
}

.c-test__your-code {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 100px #2eb135 inset;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5pc -5px 100px #2eb135 inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="c-test c-test__ok">
  DIV with OKish shadow
</div>

<div class="c-test c-test__your-code">
  Your CSS
</div>
```